# Problema com Gravação de Arquivo txt em C++

Tags: c++

Sempre que tento gravar algo novo nesse arquivo, ele apaga o que estava salvo antes, fica sempre salvando em cima do que tinha antes, alguém sabe me dizer o que é?

```
arquivo = fopen("dados.txt","w");
aux     = x.retorne_energia();
aux2    = x.retorna_nome();
fprintf(arquivo,"%d\t",aux);
fputs(aux2.c_str(), arquivo);
aux     = y.retorne_energia();
aux2    = y.retorna_nome();
fprintf(arquivo,"\n%d\t",aux);
fputs(aux2.c_str(), arquivo);
fclose(arquivo);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faz sentido esse comportamento, ao abrir o arquivo com `fopen("nome_do_arquivo","w")`, você está abrindo em modo de **escrita**. Segundo a [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/):

> write: Create an empty file for output operations. If a file with the same name already exists, its contents are discarded and the file is treated as a new empty file.

Isso é, se o arquivo já existe, ele trata como um novo arquivo (descartando o conteúdo anterior).

Para funcionar como deseja, recomendo o uso do modo **"a"** (append). Nesse modo, se o arquivo já existe ele posiciona o cursor para o final do arquivo. Caso contrário o arquivo é criado.

Dê uma olhada em [`fopen` no cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) e [`fopen` no opengroup.com](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html).

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!